# Ejecutar función al crear orden WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de ejecutar una función al momento de crear una orden en WooCommerce. He visto el modulo de Code Snippets pero no se como se llama la función que crea la orden ni como hacer para dispararla.

La idea es que cuando un cliente cree una nueva orden se haga una petición POST a mi servidor para enviar una notificación al móvil del usuario.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: fijate si alguna de estas actions te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/362227/81450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné con el siguiente hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'nombreFuncion' );

function nombreFuncion( $order_id ) {

}
```

Usando el plugin de code snippets de Wordpress.