# Enviar email con woocommerce por un pedido procesando

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Quiero enviar dos correos después del checkout.

1.- El que envía automáticamente woocommerce con el pago, el total en €, etc.

2.- Un email con información adicional.

He estado mirando y no se puede hacer desde el mismo woocommerce y no puedo utiliar plugins, tiene que ser en código.

Después de mucho buscar, creo que sería algo así.

(El order status control es `processing` y no ````completed``` porque estoy haciendo pruebas con una tarjeta de test de stripe y stripe, en modo pruebas, no te deja el pedido como completado, si no como procesando).

Lo que tengo por el momento en mi archivo `functions.php` es lo siguiente:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

function order_processing( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $to_email = $order["billing_address"];
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <alexiglesiasvortex@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', '<h1>This is a test for my new processing email.</h1><p>Agree, this is a test</p>', $headers );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_processing', 'order_processing' );
```

Actualmente esto no me funcione, es decir, no me da ningún error y el checkout finaliza correctamente pero no me llega ningún correo al email que puse en mi formulario (billing_address).

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable?
Muchas gracias de antelación y que paséis un feliz lunes.

Comment: mira en: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/adding-a-second-email-address-to-a-completed-order-in-woocommerce

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero yo no necesito enviar el mismo correo a dos destinatarios, necesito enviar dos correos distintos a un solo destinatario, ¿sabes? ¡Muchas gracias de todas formas por las molestias!

Comment: refs de hooks https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/362227/81450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el punto 1, que es solo enviar una copia del correo del pago completado, puedes enviar un correo de copia con el siguiente código, :

```
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_email_headers',
  'bbloomer_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc2',
   9999, 3 
);
 
function bbloomer_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc2(
  $headers, $email_id, $order
){
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email_id ) {
        $headers .= "Bcc: Correo <correo@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

Para el punto 2, muy probablemente tengas que crear una plantilla de correo

ref
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-to-cc-bcc-order-email-recipients/